Code shows in Greek letters
I have been trying to insert an Octave function in my paper but when I build the pdf the letters  are all turned into greek.(The rest of the paper is written in greek). What is even weirder is that the comments on the code which are written in greek are also not printed properly How to print the code normally?

My TeX looks like this:
\documentclass[A4, twosided]{article}
%ΠΑΚΕΤΑ------------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{alphabeta}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{yhmath}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{relsize}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{titletoc}
 \usepackage{fdsymbol}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{listings}
 %\usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
 \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
 language=Java,
 aboveskip=3mm,
 belowskip=3mm,
 showstringspaces=false,
 columns=flexible,
 basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
 numbers=none,
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
 keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
 stringstyle=\color{mauve},
 breaklines=true,
 breakatwhitespace=true,
 tabsize=3
}
\begin{document}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Octave]
function [Inv,P]=GJinv(A)
 format rat
 n=length(A);
 P=eye(n); #Πίνακας Μεταθέσεων
 Inv=[A,eye(n)]; #Αρχικοποιώ τον αντίστροφο ως τον επαυξημένο Α|Ι
 for k=1:n
       #βρισκω το στοιχειο στην αριστερή στήλη με τη μεγαλύτερη απόλυτη τιμή
       [~,r] = max(abs(A(k:end,k)));
       r = n-(n-k+1)+r;    
       #αλλάζω γραμμές#
       Inv([k r],:) = Inv([r k],:);
       P([k r],:) = P([r k],:);
       #διαιρώ με οδηγό και φτιάχνω τους πινακες
       Inv(k,:) = Inv(k,:) / Inv(k,k);
       for i=1:n
         if i~=k
           Inv(i,:)=Inv(i,:)-(Inv(i,k)*Inv(k,:)); #προσοχή έχουμε ήδη διαρέσει με Ακκ
         endif
       endfor
 endfor
 Inv=Inv(1:n,n+1:2*n);
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

If I remove the \UseRawInputEncoding I am getting a bunch of errors Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Welcome! Can you just compile with LuaTeX and remove that line?

I'd recommend removing the \UseRawInputEncoding line and compiling with luaTeX. Then it compiles without error.
Note that neither A4 nor twosided are valid options for article. I assume you want a4paper and twoside here.
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\babelfont{tt}{Source Code Pro}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
 language=Java,
 aboveskip=3mm,
 belowskip=3mm,
 showstringspaces=false,
 columns=flexible,
 basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
 numbers=none,
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
 keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
 stringstyle=\color{mauve},
 breaklines=true,
 breakatwhitespace=true,
 tabsize=3
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Octave]
function [Inv,P]=GJinv(A)
 format rat
 n=length(A);
 P=eye(n); #Πίνακας Μεταθέσεων
 Inv=[A,eye(n)]; #Αρχικοποιώ τον αντίστροφο ως τον επαυξημένο Α|Ι
 for k=1:n
       #βρισκω το στοιχειο στην αριστερή στήλη με τη μεγαλύτερη απόλυτη τιμή
       [~,r] = max(abs(A(k:end,k)));
       r = n-(n-k+1)+r;    
       #αλλάζω γραμμές#
       Inv([k r],:) = Inv([r k],:);
       P([k r],:) = P([r k],:);
       #διαιρώ με οδηγό και φτιάχνω τους πινακες
       Inv(k,:) = Inv(k,:) / Inv(k,k);
       for i=1:n
         if i~=k
           Inv(i,:)=Inv(i,:)-(Inv(i,k)*Inv(k,:)); #προσοχή έχουμε ήδη διαρέσει με Ακκ
         endif
       endfor
 endfor
 Inv=Inv(1:n,n+1:2*n);
endfunction
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


If this isn't an option, you should still remove \UseRawInputEncoding, but you will need to troubleshoot the undeclared characters and set up suitable fonts for Greek using a traditional font encoding (presumably LG1). This is not too bad in this case, because the characters are visible ones. Compile on the command line to the first error. The character at the end of the first line of the error message is the problem. Either retype, if appropriate, or declare it, if it is correct, but you will have to check the character is available in the output. This will be complicated by the fact that your input is code.
